# How to take a screenshot inside my android app

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to take a screenshot from inside my android application. I'm using some code I found online as I'm new to java. Here is what I have so far.

```
public void screenshot(View view){
    View v = view.getRootView();
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap b = v.getDrawingCache();
    String extr = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myPath = new File(extr, getString(R.string.new_image)+".jpg");
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(myPath);
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage( getContentResolver(), b,
                "Screen", "screen");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I press the button that calls my method this is what the log says:

W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/newimg.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

these are the permissions I have in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission
    android:required="true"
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission
    android:required="true"
    android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission
    android:required="true"
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission
    android:required="true"
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission
    android:required="true"
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Also if anyone would like to help me further I also would love to know how to take a screenshot of just a certain portion of the screen such as my VideoView
widget instead of the whole screen(or possibly a way to crop the screenshot before storing it to the gallery/sd).

Any tips much appreciated.

Comment: running on emulator?try it in real device or bluestacks

Answer (score 0):

You have to ask for permission at run-time otherwise EACCES (Permission denied) occurs see M Docs on android site [Requesting Permissions](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

add permission which you want to use in the list

```
    String[] perms = {"android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO", "android.permission.CAMERA"};
    int permsRequestCode = 200; 
    requestPermissions(perms, permsRequestCode);
```

will trigger this on user behavior of granting them or not

```
@Override

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int permsRequestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults){

    switch(permsRequestCode){

        case 200:

            boolean audioAccepted = grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

            boolean cameraAccepted = grantResults[1]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

            break;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**try below code:**

```
public void screenshot(View view){
    View v = view.getRootView();
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap b = v.getDrawingCache();
    File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "/Your Folder Name");
    root.mkdir();
    Calendar localCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    String fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss").format(localCalendar.getTime());
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(root.getAbsolutePath(), fileName + ".jpg"));
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    //After run code See your folder     
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Add to Androidmanifest.xml File**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```